# What mangement tools does SQL server 2008 R2 standard edition (with SBS) ship with

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, small-business-server

I'm considering purchasing SBS 2008 and wanted to know the tools SQL Server Standard ships with.

Here is a MS article with all the tools. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144275.aspx

I developed an ERP on SQL Server 2008 Enterprise and would migrate that into the new server. I used the "SQL Server Management Studio" and "Server Profiler" tools very frequently when developing and would still need them to do many tasks.

Are those two tools included in the Standard edition too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Check the article that's [linked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx) from the one you posted.